# Migrating to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to migrate a web to `mysqli` and have my first question:

In mysql I had this:

```
$sel_user="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user='$usuario_tienda'";
$rs_user=mysql_query($sel_user);
$tienda=mysql_result($rs_user,0,"tienda");
```

When I change to mysqli it looks like this:

```
$consulta_user="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$usuario_tienda'";
$query_user = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta_user);
$resultado_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_user);
$tienda= $resultado_user['tienda'];
```

It works, but I don't think this is the best way to do it, can I do more efficient, more compressed?

Comment: Looks like you have a SQL injection in both piece of code?

Comment: You should also consider moving to prepared statements. It's more work, but your code becomes safer.

Comment: I'm a newbie in all of this (searching for examples when I need to do something). I thought SQL injection is a way of hacking... what do you mean Halfer? Prepared statements is PDO? I've seen this way of make the code, but think to dificult for my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use prepared statement, using that you can avoid sql-injection hack

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user=:user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $usuario_tienda);
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
$resultado_user = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $resultado_user['tienda'];
```

Comment: this will make the consult (I think), but how can I get the $tienda value?

Comment: thanks!!! I'll try this way... I thought it will be more conpressed but if it's more secure I prefer. thanks a lot!